# Issue with named and default imports on react app on stackblitz

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a sample React app on Stackblitz and I have the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { MyContext } from './MyContext';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve('some value from promise').then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setMyValue(res);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <MyContext.provider value="{{myValue}}">
      <div>
        <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      </div>
    </MyContext.provider>
  );
}
```

As you can see for yourself (see link below), I have not mixed ***default*** and ***named*** imports but still I get the above error...

Here is the complete app on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xkxhxk?file=src/App.js

If I comment out the `<MyContext.provider` tag, then the app works. The error message seems misleading.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `<MyContext.Provider>` not `<MyContext.provider>`

Comment: Well spotted Saransh. Thanks a lot!! The error message is misleading still...

Comment: Could be. 
My first guess was react functional component only works when their first word is capitalized.

Comment: @AndreasJagiella, not _entirely_ correct, it should be `value={{myValue}}`. No quotes, but double curly braces because it's an object.